# OpenCV error: No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found

Tags: windows, opencv, visual-studio-2015, cmake-gui

> "CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:114 (project): No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found"

This is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3RJ3.png) I get while installing OpenCV, do I need to find the path of the c++ compiler and if so, how?